# how to set default value in form of tags wordpress

Tags: wordpress, forms, tags

i need to show in default value my text and not first tag, how i can do this?

```
<?php
if ($tags = get_tags( array('orderby' => 'name') ))
{
    echo '<form action="'.get_bloginfo('url').'" method="get">';
    echo '<select name="tag" id="tag" class="postform">';
    foreach ($tags as $tag)
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$tag->slug.'">'.$tag->name.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select> ';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="view" />';
    echo '</form>';
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood the question, you need to select the default tag in a drop-down list, and not the first one. Then you just need to check the value of slug and add `selected` attribute to an element when it is needed.

```
$default = 'default-tag-slug'; // set the default value
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    echo '<option value="'.$tag->slug.'" '.( $tag->slug == $default ? 'selected' : '' ).' >'.$tag->name.'</option>';
}
```